# Bootstrap - Change rows and columns order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap is it possible to have these two different layouts depending on the viewport? I've been searching about this and I'm aware of the concepts [push, pull](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) and [responsive utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) but the examples I've found had simpler structures.

On this case, I rather not use responsive utilities (because there would be lots of repeated processing) and/or JavaScript, just HTML and CSS manipulation.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mehfb6p0/) with the wrong layout on smartphones...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 elA">Title A</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 elB">Title B</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 elC">Title C</div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 elA">Graph A</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 elB">Graph B</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 elC">Graph C</div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 elA">List A</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 elB">List B</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 elC">List C</div>
</div>
```

> Tablets and desktops layout

[image: Tablets and desktops layout]

> Smartphones layout

[image]

Comment: If this is even possible, it's news to me.

Comment: Had a similar issue. What I ended up doing was loading the section twice and hiding the one I didn't need. However, in my case, the section was very short and contained only text. So I'm not sure, if that's something you'd want to do.

Comment: On my case, I'd prefer not to use that approach because on the best scenario, I'd have to render six big lists instead of three.

Comment: I think an approach I would use is check the user agent on the server side, and apply an extra stylesheet for mobile browsers.

Comment: i have a solution but only if the list as the same disposition as the other element (three in a row) http://jsfiddle.net/mehfb6p0/1/

Comment: with a little trick, we can do want you want but i'm not sur it will work for 6 element : http://jsfiddle.net/mehfb6p0/3/

Comment: ekans that's a neat solution! It works nicely but I'll do some more tests. Thanks! I'd like to see more solutions for this :)

Comment: Check my solution I bet is better than @ekans

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found this question today and saw no such answer that would satisfy the OP and the future visitors of this post. Thus, decided to answer it with current bootstrap 4 version:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 order-1">
    <div class="m-3 bg-warning">Title A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 order-4 order-md-2">
    <div class="m-3 bg-success">Title B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 order-7 order-md-3">
    <div class="m-3 bg-info">Title C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 order-2 order-md-4">
    <div class="m-3 bg-warning">Graph A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 order-5 order-md-5">
    <div class="m-3 bg-success">Graph B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 order-8 order-md-6">
    <div class="m-3 bg-info">Graph C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 order-3 order-md-7">
    <div class="m-3 bg-warning">List A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 order-6 order-md-8">
    <div class="m-3 bg-success">List B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 order-9">
    <div class="m-3 bg-info">List C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the [demo for bootstrap 4 row and column ordering](https://www.bootply.com/m9gaUjURPu). I hope, you'll be able to manage column ordering in bootstrap 3 as well if you are working on it.

Comment: thank you! I'm still in awe. this is so powerful! WOW!

Comment: Please use Flexbox (bootstrap 4). All major browsers now support this.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 solutions without using Javascript

**First Option:**

The element list is using Responsive Utilities Classes

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Check this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ppollono/mehfb6p0/12/

For the list in the first row

```
class="visible-xs"
```

For the list at the bottom

```
class="hidden-xs"
```

CONTS: element list is duplicated

**Second Option:**

Use Flex display

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Check this example:
http://codepen.io/Palapas/pen/LVvbyW?editors=110

```css
.row {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #999;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.row div {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}
.elA {
  background-color: #E99048;
}
.elB {
  background-color: #B0C07E;
}
.elC {
  background-color: #B0B9DC;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row .et {
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
    width: 30%;
  }
  .row .eg {
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
    width: 30%;
  }
  .row .el {
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="et elA">Title A: Integer et fermentum leo. In sollicitudin arcu eget nisi pretium.</div>
  <div class="eg elA">Graph A: Integer et fermentum leo. In sollicitudin arcu eget nisi pretium, viverra rutrum neque malesuada. Cras maximus nibh quis ex varius feugiat. Ut nec arcu nunc.
  </div>
  <div class="el elA">List A
    <br>
    <ul>
      <li>Sed adipiscing ornare risus. Morbi est est, blandit sit amet, sagittis vel, euismod vel, velit. Pellentesque egestas sem. Suspendisse commodo ullamcorper magna.</li>
      <li>Nulla sed leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</li>
      <li>Fusce lacinia arcu et nulla. Nulla vitae mauris non felis mollis faucibus.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</li>
      <li>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</li>
      <li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
      <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
      <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li>
      <li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="et elB">Title B: Integer et fermentum leo.
  </div>
  <div class="eg elB">Graph B</div>
  <div class="el elB">List B
    <br>
    <ul>
      <li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
      <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
      <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li>
      <li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li>
      <li>Sed adipiscing ornare risus. Morbi est est, blandit sit amet, sagittis vel, euismod vel, velit. Pellentesque egestas sem. Suspendisse commodo ullamcorper magna.</li>
      <li>Nulla sed leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</li>
      <li>Fusce lacinia arcu et nulla. Nulla vitae mauris non felis mollis faucibus.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</li>
      <li>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</li>
      <li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
      <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
      <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li>
      <li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li>
      <li>Sed adipiscing ornare risus. Morbi est est, blandit sit amet, sagittis vel, euismod vel, velit. Pellentesque egestas sem. Suspendisse commodo ullamcorper magna.</li>
      <li>Nulla sed leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</li>
      <li>Fusce lacinia arcu et nulla. Nulla vitae mauris non felis mollis faucibus.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="et elC">Title C: Integer et fermentum leo. In sollicitudin arcu eget nisi pretium, viverra rutrum neque malesuada. Cras maximus nibh quis ex varius feugiat.</div>
  <div class="eg elC">Graph C</div>
  <div class="el elC">List C
    <br>
    <ul>
      <li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
      <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
      <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet,
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CONTS: not supported by IE9 and below http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 3):

Probably bit late to the party, but you can easily fix this with some lines of css and flexbox. I don't know if bootstrap provides something similar.

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.row > div {
    width: 100%;
}

.elA {
    order: 1;
}

.elB { 
    order: 2;
}

.elC {
    order: 3;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/t284d3mg/

Flexbox is perfectly explained at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Be aware that older browser don't support flexbox, have an old specification implemented or that you need to add prefixes.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for? 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

I use media queries all the time for that sort of things.

I can use it in two ways.
first, define stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 799px)" />
```

Second, define media query in stylesheet:

```
@media handheld and (min-width: 20em), screen and (min-width: 20em) { ... }
```

Hope i didn't misunderstood your question :D