# Is there a way to re-position DOM elements using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="red" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; color: red"></div>
        <div class="blue" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; color: blue"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
<style>
 .boxes{display:flex; flex-direction:row;}
</style>
```

is there a way using CSS or javascript to put div.blue in the position of div.red
or div.red in the position of div.blue

Comment: Yes there is. But if that's not the answer you wanted, you'll have to rewrite your question a bit because DOM manipulation using JS is a pretty basic topic and has _tons_ of tutorials online, so you should be able to pretty much immediately find something that teaches you how to do that, with a cursory web search. Find one (that teaches modern JS, of course), follow it, and if you get stuck, that's the time to post to Stackoverflow. Not before you did any [searching on your own](/help/how-to-ask). The same goes for CSS positioning (search for `flexbox`)

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48205947/2138752

Comment: From your example, you don't need to use javascript -- but if you do (for whatever reason) it's fairly simple. `document.getElementsByClassName("boxes")[0].appendChild(document.getElementsByClassName("boxes")[0].childNodes[1])`

Answer (score 4):

No js needed to sort the elements.

See if this is what you're looking for

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
}

.blue {
  order: 1;
}

.red {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="red" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: red"></div>
        <div class="blue" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: blue"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by CSS `flex` property. Just set the `boxes` element's `flex-direction` to `row-reverse`.

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="red" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: red"></div>
        <div class="blue" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: blue"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note**

If you want to display the two boxes vertically aligned then use `flex-direction: column-reverse;` instead of `row-reverse`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the parent node ('.boxes'), then get the childs indexes and swap:

```
childNode[1].parentNode.insertBefore(childNode[1], childNode[0]);
```

Comment: but this only swaps 2 elements what if I have multiple boxes on my website and I wanted to arrange them anyhow I wanted to, for example, => [div1, div2, div3, div5, div5] can be customized to give => [div4, div1, div3, div2, div5]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this the way you want to.

```js
document.querySelector(".red").addEventListener("mouseover",()=>{
document.querySelector(".red").style.background="blue"
document.querySelector(".blue").style.background="red"

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="red" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: red"></div>
        <div class="blue" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: blue"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
<style>
 .boxes{display:flex; flex-direction:row;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Little ugly code.

```
    var redtag = document.getElementsByClassName("boxes")[0].getElementsByClassName("red")[0];
    redtag.remove();
    var bluetag = document.getElementsByClassName("boxes")[0].getElementsByClassName("blue")[0];
    bluetag.remove();
    document.getElementsByClassName("boxes")[0].appendChild(bluetag);
    document.getElementsByClassName("boxes")[0].appendChild(redtag);
```